# С чего начать изучать разработку под Android на Java

Tags: java, android

Привет всем! Посоветуйте содержательный видео-курс на русском по разработке под Android на Java. Спасибо заранее.

Comment: Никогда не воспринимал все эти видео-курсы всерьез. Они для ленивых: сел, включил видео и смотришь как фильм, попутно поедая чипсы, а толку потом - ноль. Мой Вам совет – изучайте Android по книгам, коих немало.

Comment: а какая из них лично Вам по душе?
P.S.: спасибо за исправление, наверное мне пора спать))

Comment: https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/135513511/, она есть в свободном для скачивания доступе (нужно именно 2-е издание, которое 2016 года).

Comment: Статьи. Никаких книг и видеоуроки. СТАТЬИ, блоги, G+, гитхаб. Только практика. Только хардкор

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Посмотрите видео канала startandroid на YouTube. Очень много уроков.